# Can I use fastcgi_finish_request() like register_shutdown_function?

Tags: fastcgi, php

This simple method for caching dynamic content uses `register_shutdown_function()` to push the output buffer to a file on disk after exiting the script. However, I'm using **PHP-FPM**, with which this doesn't work; a 5-second sleep added to the function indeed causes a 5-second delay in executing the script from the browser. A commenter in the PHP docs notes that there's a special function for PHP-FPM users, namely `fastcgi_finish_request()`. There's not much documentation for this particular function, however.

The point of `fastcgi_finish_request()` seems to be to flush all data and proceed with other tasks, but what I want to achieve, as would normally work with `register_shutdown_function()`, is basically to put the contents of the output buffer into a file without the user having to wait for this to finish.

Is there any way to achieve this under PHP-FPM, with `fastcgi_finish_request()` or another function?

```
$timeout = 3600; // cache time-out
$file = '/home/example.com/public_html/cache/' . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // unique id for this page
if (file_exists($file) && (filemtime($file) + $timeout) > time()) {
  readfile($file);
  exit();
} else {
  ob_start();
  register_shutdown_function(function () use ($file) {
    // sleep(5);
    $content = ob_get_flush();
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
  });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a 5-second sleep?

Comment: I don't, it's just to illustrate that the 5-second sleep is visible to the user, when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use `fastcgi_finish_request` for that. You can save this file and see that it works:

```
<?php

$timeout = 3600; // cache time-out
$file = '/home/galymzhan/www/ps/' . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // unique id for this page
if (file_exists($file) && (filemtime($file) + $timeout) > time()) {
  echo "Got this from cache<br>";
  readfile($file);
  exit();
} else {
  ob_start();
  echo "Content to be cached<br>";

  $content = ob_get_flush();
  fastcgi_finish_request();
  // sleep(5);

  file_put_contents($file, $content);
}
```

Even if you uncomment the line with `sleep(5)`, you'll see that page still opens instantly because `fastcgi_finish_request` sends data back to browser and then proceeds with whatever code is written after it.

Comment: Thanks for providing a code sample, because I mistook the fastcgi_finish_request function to work similar to register_shutdown, in that I could declare it at the beginning and it, too, would "register shutdown" of the script. Obviously, the difference is that I have to call fastcgi_finish_request at the end of the script, with all the content to be cached in between. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**,
If you cache the dynamic content this way, you're doing it wrong. Surely it can be used this way and it will be able to work, but its totally paralyzed by the approach itself.

if you want to efficiently cache and handle content, create one class and wrap all caching function into.

Yes, you can use `fast_cgi_finish_request()` like a `register_shutdown()`. The only difference is that, `fast_cgi_finish_request()` will send an output(if any) and **WILL NOT TERMINATE** the script, while an callback of `register_shutdown()` will be invoked on script termination.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer isn't clear to me. How is this "totally paralyzed be the approach itself"? And what would be the major benefit of wrapping this into a single class?

Comment: The major benefit of wrapping into the class is that, you keep strongly separating each responsibility "for its own job", thus implementing a **Single Responsibly Principle** (google for this). Another thing I'd suggest: If you want a good cache wrapper for dynamic content, look at its popular implementations. (ex: Zend Framework/Cache) Get some ideas from there, then adopt for your own needs. While `fastcgi_finish_request()` would perfectly work for this, you're clearly breaking `SOLID` principles.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I don't think any of the answers correctly answer the problem.

As I understand it, the problem is that none of the output gets sent to the client until the ob_get_flush() call that happens during the shutdown function.

To fix that issue, you need to pass a function and a chunk size to ob_start() in order to handle the output in chunks.

Something like this for your else clause:

```
$content = '';

$write_buffer_func = function($buffer, $phase) use ($file, &$content) {
  $content .= $buffer;
  if ($phase & PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FINAL) {
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
  }
  return $buffer;
};

ob_start($write_buffer_func, 1024);
```